# ¿Declarar tablas temporales dentro de un ciclo?

Tags: sql-server

Me asignaron un procedimiento almacenado para corregir errores, el cual trae una lista de clientes para generar factura a cada uno, para recorrerlos se utiliza un while, dentro de este se declaran variables de tablas temporales, se limpian y luego se llenan. Mi pregunta es porque esto no me arroja error ya que no se borran las tablas sino que continuamente se vuelven a declarar, y si esto afecta el rendimiento del procedimiento?

```
WHILE(@cont<=@totalclientes)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DetalleFactura TABLE (
        ID int Identity(1,1),
        DETALLE [varchar](30)
    ) 

    DELETE FROM @DetalleFactura

    INSERT INTO @DetalleFactura VALUES('Producto')
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que el `DECLARE` es una clausula que se resuelve en tiempo de compilación, pero no participa en el código final (compilado) que termina ejecutándose, la única condición mandatoria, es que se defina antes de usar efectivamente la variable.

Un ejemplo simpático y claro es el siguiente:

```
IF 1 = 0 BEGIN
  DECLARE @MiVariable INT
END ELSE BEGIN
  SET @MiVariable = 1
END
PRINT @MiVariable
```

Si el `DECLARE` se resolviera en tiempo de ejecución, sin duda esto daría error ya que nunca se daría la condición `1 = 0` por lo que el `DECLARE` nunca se invocaría, sin embargo esto funciona perfectamente. El `DECLARE` aparece antes del uso de la variable, por lo que el motor al "compilar" el lote completo ya asigno el espacio en memoria y el tipo de datos para manejar la variable, mucho antes de la ejecución en sí de las sentencias completas del script.

En tu caso, ocurre algo parecido, tienes un solo `DECLARE` dentro del loop pero antes de la necesidad de usar dicha variable (lo que es válido), en la compilación se declara y reserva el espacio para `@DetalleFactura` y luego simplemente la sentencia `DECLARE` es ignorada directamente en el código final compilado.

Volviendo a tu pregunta, el `DECLARE` dentro del loop no debería tener ningún impacto en la performance.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando unas clausulas que se emplean mas que todo para definir variables y para trabajar en tiempo de ejecucion, en tu caso emplearía algo asi como esto:

```
BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #DetalleFactura (
            ID int Identity(1,1),
            DETALLE [varchar](30)       
        )       
        insert into #DetalleFactura value ('Producto')
END

/**al final de tu ciclo aplica lo siguiente**/
Drop table #DetalleFactura
```

Esto para que cada vez que ejecutes borres la tabla y tengas datos nuevos